# AWS Amplify - How to query GraphQL when some of the data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

When using the AWS AppSync console, I can run this query and get a return...

```
  listAccounts {
    items {
      name
      cameras {
        items {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the same query from inside my react app using

```
await API.graphql({ query: queries.listAccounts })
```

I get an error...

```
"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'items' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'items'"
```

My issue is that an Account will not always have a camera, in which case I would like to be able to get the response and still display the camera data.  Can anyone help me out here.  Is there some way to 'allow' undefined?